# Vaadin TabSheet tab size

Tags: vaadin

I have a Vaadin TabSheet and I created 4 Tabs, but I want all these 4 tabs to spread for the whole width of my Tabsheet. Currently they only span about 50% of the width.

I have tried setSizeFull(), setWidth("100%") on the tab object as well as tabsheet object and it doesnt help.

Please let me know if anybody has any idea how to do it.

thanks
dheeraj

Answer (score 4):

For a very crude, brute method, you could try the following:

```
.v-tabsheet-tabitemcell {
    width: 25%;
}

.v-tabsheet-tabitem .v-caption {
    width: auto !important;
}
```

Note, though, that this might break something in some browsers, especially in older IE's, so be sure to test thoroughly.

Oh, and that's CSS you need to include in a custom theme, if it wasn't obvious from the above snippet :)